# Is it safe to disable system google apps

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, htc-sense, disable-app

I am looking on to using some of the applications provided from the manufacturer and was wondering if it is safe to disable some google applications.

I am looking to disable:

- GMail (this is my biggest concern ATM)
- Chrome
- G+ (that annoying 'photos' app)
- Play News, Music, Newsstand (I believe these are safe)

If you know any applications which are totally not safe (excluding the core ones, like Google Play Services, etc.)

My device is:

stock HTC One (M9)
 Android 5.0.2

Comment: Yes You can disable all these... I have also disabled them all...including text to speech, hangouts etc...

Comment: Confirmed @Dalvik – very same thing here (on those devices still having GApps installed, that is :)

Comment: @Izzy I know what you mean, but usually for a few months I stay stock to make sure the device itself is fine (no factory defects) and we all know what happens then :)

Comment: Sure thing – that comment was not meant to critisize! I usually start "custom-romming" once the warranty ran out – but root the device even before unpacking :)

Comment: Google Play Services and Play Store may seem to be the core (being part of /system) but they can be safely disabled on Lollipop too. Android OS doesn't depend upon them unless HTC made it compulsory which is unlikely from consumer standpoint.

Comment: I think memory(both RAM and app size) they use is the biggest concern of yours like me. I have disabled them all too. It is safe and I have gained some space :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer** : Yes

> These are just apps and you can disable it.But, when the app(any app),
>   *for example the app need to update* and you cannot update the app when it search for ***Google play(for example)*** to update and you
>   need to new market for update the app.

---

also, as you said :

- GMail (this is my biggest concern ATM)
- Chrome
- Google + (that annoying 'photos' app)
- Play News, Music, Newsstand

these are always safe to disable and if you don't using of them, you can disable it for reasons like,

clear the ram and it means, the phone speed can up.!

good day.